# strange +5 upvote

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Ordinary upvoting **an answer** on SO adds +10, but today I get `+5 upvote`

is it a bug or a new feature?

Comment: Can you post a link to the answer?

Comment: Thanx. That's it. I didn't know about "rep cap". Where I can read about this magick number?

Comment: @fl00r, from the faq: " A maximum of 30 votes can be cast per user per day, and you can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day (although accepted answers and bounty awards are immune to this limit). Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate reputation."

Comment: Thanx, I've found it already. Didn't know about this :)

Comment: @fl00r: By the way, it's "thanks".

Comment: Ok, @CanSpice :) but it is from http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @fl00r: read the comments to the answer you're referring to...

Comment: @Michael Petrotta, mm?

Comment: @fl00r: I'd assumed you were referring to [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/origin-of-the-word-goodbye/1507#1507) when you spoke of [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: No, I was speaking about whole site )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You hit the Rep cap of [200 Rep from upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), so only half of an upvote counted for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619694/how-to-upgrade-rails-project-from-rail-3-0-5-to-3-0-6/5619716#5619716).

You can usually find these sorts of details (i.e. what posts got you what Rep, how many upvotes you've gotten for the day, etc.) broken down in [your user profile Rep graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298624/fl00r?tab=reputation) (the graph even shows the 200 Rep threshold).

Comment: that's the answer! Thanx.

Comment: I clicked your link, but didn't see anything there about the '200 Rep from upvotes'.  I see the daily 200 limit, but that's it.  Can you update the link to show specifically where that's said? (I just got hit with the +5 thing too.)

Comment: @MarquelV: The line that mentions the maximum 200 reputation per day also states that "accepted answers and bounty awards are immune to this limit", thus the limit only applies to Rep from votes. A little more detail can be found [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/daily-dose-of-daily-reputation-ca/).